# Can't access my websites from my home network. Router, ISP or something else?

Tags: website, isp, blocking

I'm having trouble accessing my websites. Here's the problem and the steps that I've already taken to try to debug the problem:

1. Yesterday I was in the middle of updating my website. One moment it was working fine, then the next moment when I hit refresh, the website failed to load. In chrome it says "This webpage is not available. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".
2. I have three websites hosted with the same shared hosting plan with Siteground. I tested all three websites and I am unable to access any of them.
3. I checked all three websites on http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com. For all three, the problem is just me.
4. I checked the three websites on different browsers and different devices. They also do not work. However, when I turn the WiFi off on my phone and use my phone's network, the websites work fine.
5. I did a reverse IP domain check on http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/ to find out what other websites share my websites' ip address. When I try to go to them, they also do not work (but they do work on my phone that has WIFI turned off). So it looks like I can't access any websites that are hosted on the same web server from just my home network.
6. I am able to successfully ping all of the websites.
7. I tried restarting the router. I still get the same results.
8. When searching forums for a solution, I've seen it mentioned a couple of times to do a tracert. So I did that and here are the results. However, I don't know how to interpret the output.

   ```
   tracert beetifulbookcovers.com

   Tracing route to beetifulbookcovers.com [184.154.244.76]
   over a maximum of 30 hops:

     1     9 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  dsldevice.attlocal.net [192.168.1.254]
     2    22 ms    24 ms    24 ms  108-203-164-2.lightspeed.frokca.sbcglobal.net [108.203.164.2]
     3    23 ms    21 ms    21 ms  75.29.64.138
     4    23 ms    23 ms    24 ms  12.83.77.145
     5    24 ms    27 ms    26 ms  gar23.sffca.ip.att.net [12.122.114.5]
     6    27 ms    27 ms    30 ms  192.205.32.210
     7    77 ms    75 ms    73 ms  ae-1-3515.ear2.Chicago2.Level3.net [4.69.134.46]

     8    97 ms    97 ms    97 ms  4.15.84.6
     9   103 ms   104 ms   104 ms  128.177.133.154
    10    98 ms    97 ms    95 ms  placeholder.sgded.com [184.154.244.76]

   Trace complete.
   ```
9. I tried accessing my sites using the free proxy server at hidemyass.com/proxy and I am able to go to them just fine.

And that's all of the steps I've taken so far. I'm not sure where I should go from here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try use ultrasurf, if it works probably your IP is being blocked by siteground

Comment: I installed ultrasurf and I was able to access the site. Thank you for that suggestion. I've contacted Siteground support and you are right. My IP was being blocked by one of their firewalls. Siteground is going to remove the block and send me more information on why it was blocked.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what HTTP service you're using to host your website. But may I remind you that HTTP servers are posted on port 80. So maybe go inside your config files for your HTTP server and change it to port 80. Then it should probably work. I hope this helpped you.